# Is there a way to determine unnecessary exclusions in Findbugs?

Tags: findbugs

With findbugs, one can define exclusions for various bugs at the method, class, or project level. Sometimes an exclusion will no longer be relevant due to further development of the code. Is there a way to tell when there are unnecessary exclusions?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that does the following things:

- Remove single exclusion from exclusion file using regular expression
- Execute e.g. `mvn findbugs:check` and check return code
- If return code is different than 0, bring the exclusion back
- Go to next exclusion and repeat

I don't think there is ready solution for that, but I agree - this could be quite useful to have.